# How to get the empty row on click of add button using primeng in angular2

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-reactive-forms

I have a section with add button,if i click on add button, i get the fields with the prefilled values as the one already present.
I want to get the empty fields on click of add button and if the section is empty then automatically one new field must appear.

HTML:

```
<div formArrayName="Communicationx" *ngFor="let item of emrPatientdetailsForm.get('Communicationx').controls; let i = index;">

              <div [formGroupName]="i">
                <div class="col-sm-4 pull-left m-b10 m-t10">
                  <label class="col-sm-5 pull-left col-form-label g-color-gray-dark-v2 g-font-weight-700 text-sm-left no-padd">Preferred</label>
                  <!-- <div class="col-sm-7 pull-left no-padd">
                    <div class="input-group g-brd-primary--focus">
                      <input class="form-control form-control-md rounded-0 pr-0" type="text" OnlyNumber="true" maxlength="3" placeholder="Preferred"
                        formControlName="Preferred">
                    </div>
                  </div> -->
                  <div class="col-sm-7 pull-left no-padd">
                      <input type='text' (keyup)="searchDropDown(30, src6.value)" #src6 formControlName="Preferred" [(ngModel)]="selectedPreferred"
                        minlength="3" placeholder="Preferred" />
                      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                      <div *ngIf="patientDropdown && patientDropdown?.preferred && IsHidden" class="emr-dropdown">
                        <ul *ngFor="let preferredType of patientDropdown?.preferred" (click)="getValue(preferredType)" class="p-l10 m-b0 brd-b">
                          <li>
                            {{preferredType.Description}}
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 pull-left m-b10 m-t10">
                  <label class="col-sm-5 pull-left col-form-label g-color-gray-dark-v2 g-font-weight-700 text-sm-left no-padd">Language</label>
                  <!-- <div class="col-sm-7 pull-left no-padd">
                    <div class="input-group g-brd-primary--focus">
                      <input class="form-control form-control-md rounded-0 pr-0" type="text" OnlyNumber="true" maxlength="3" placeholder="Language"
                        formControlName="Language">
                    </div>
                  </div> -->
                  <div class="col-sm-7 pull-left no-padd">
                      <input type='text' (keyup)="searchDropDown(176, src7.value)" #src7 formControlName="Language" [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage"
                        minlength="3" placeholder="Language" />
                      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                      <div *ngIf="patientDropdown && patientDropdown?.language && IsHidden" class="emr-dropdown">
                        <ul *ngFor="let languageType of patientDropdown?.language" (click)="getValue(languageType)" class="p-l10 m-b0 brd-b">
                          <li>
                            {{languageType.Description}}
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="col-sm-2 pull-left m-b10 m-t10" (click)="deleteCommunicationDetails(i)">
                  delete
                </a>
              </div>

            </div>
```

TS:

```
 public addCommunicationDetails() {
    this.Communicationx = <FormArray>this.emrPatientdetailsForm.get('Communicationx') as FormArray;
    this.Communicationx.push(this.createCommunicationInformation());

  }

  public deleteCommunicationDetails(i) {
    this.Communicationx = <FormArray>this.emrPatientdetailsForm.controls['Communicationx'];
    this.Communicationx.removeAt(i);
  }
```

There is no error in console as well. Kindly help

Comment: Can you rephrase that?

Comment: Thanks for the response, which part u need?

Comment: The opening paragraph. Use proper grammar and punctuation

Comment: sorry, i have updated the question

Comment: The part I don't understand is how the selection impacts the shape of the new row

Comment: I am unable to create demo of how its appearing but an example is here, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3hampn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: when i click on add button, it is giving me the fields with the value present already in previous field

Comment: Ok. So it is a copy.

Comment: ya exactly, it is giving me the copy

Answer (score 0):

Could you put your code on https://stackblitz.com ? It's not very clear and I don't understand what result you're expecting

Comment: Thanks for the response, i am not able to get the output as appearing in my application, but it is appearing in this way, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3hampn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: You need to use a FormArray for your Emergencies which contains FormGroups. Then when you click the add button, push a new empty FormGroup. Each of them is independent and can be removed easily. The whole method is explained here : https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this I reckon.

```
addCommunicationDetailsRow() {
   // shallow copy of selected or empty
  const newRowModel = {...this.selected} || {};
  this.communicationx.push(newRowModel);
  this.selected = newRowModel;
}
```

}

Then in your template

```
<button (click)="addCommunicationDetailsRow()">Add</button>

<section *ngFor="let item of items">
   <div [formGroupName]="i" (click)="selected = item">
</section>
```

Comment: I tried with ur approach but it is throwing an error as ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Well that clearly means there is no array. Your existing code doesn't handle that case so I didn't handle it either. If the array is undefined initialize it

Comment: no longer also, I edited your property name for style. Don't use Pascal case for properties.